# Easy CSS3 or lightweight java way for :focus state of form to affect rules for parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to find a way to set my same rules for #side_contact:hover to happen for #side_contact_form input:focus.

here's the site so far:

http://www.austinhomemedia.com/

In other words, I want the div that hides without a hover to stay put when the inputs of the form inside are focused. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have searched around here alot, but if I missed a relevant thread, maybe you can link me and sorry for the redundancy. I imagine the solution will be java, but it seems like there may be a pure CSS way with all this neat functionality in CSS3.

my markup:

```
<html>
    <div id="side_contact">
        <?php
            $form ="<form id='side_contact_form'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' placeholder='name' name='name' value=$name  ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>"
        ?>
    </div>
</html>
```

my styles:

```
#side_contact {
position: fixed;
left: 96%;
top: 215px;
}

#side_contact:hover {
position: fixed;
left: 84%;
top: 215px;
}

#side_contact_form:focus {
 ?
}
```

Comment: I recommend first learning the difference between Java and JavaScript.

Comment: Java is to javascript as car is to carpet...not my quote... but still. Also, don't use tables for layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery and not worry about the form at all.  Rename #side_contact:hover to .show_me then:

```
    // reveals your div when the mouse enters the div.   
    $('#side_contact).on('mouseenter',function() {  
    $(this).addClass('.show_me');  
    });  

    //hides it again when the mouse leaves the div   
    $('#side_contact').on('mouseleave',function() {  
    $(this.removeClass('.show_me');  
    });
```